# Send txt file to remote server via post

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

I'm creating a small gps program who writes the location of the user into a local file via `FileOutputStream`. How can I send the output file to a remote server I have ?

Every example I find refers only to Json or on site generated strings.

Thank you

Comment: Can't you send it as JSON?

Comment: I could have but I had difficulties with it. Whats the simplest way to turn a FileOutputStream to json ? maybe via Gson ?

Comment: So you're writing the GPS location to a file via FileOutputStream? Can you not take what you're passing into the FOS as an HTTP POST field? Edit: Example code of what you're doing would really help. This question is a little short on details.

Answer (score 0):

Set the header to signify it's plain text.

```
request.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
```